# Install components into /opt directly with install4j

Tags: install4j

I am currently installing into /opt/mycompany/. I have 2 components in my installation and they are installed as /opt/mycompany/foo and /opt/mycompany/bar.

Is it possible to directly install my components into /opt like /opt/foo and /opt/bar.
As the media configurations require us to specify a directory(mycompany) inside /opt where our components gets installed, I am not able to achieve what I want.

Currently I am using symbolic links to achieve this. Is there a better solution available for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the distribution tree, add an installation root `/opt` and add files under that root. See

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/files.html

for more information.

However, you always need an installation directory that is not directly `/opt`, because it contains the `.install4j` runtime directory.